# Searchbar not displaying rel tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, rel

I have set a rel tag to display some text in my searchbar.
For some odd reason it does not show the text on the homepage:
http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl/

```
<input type="text" id="search" title="" name="s" class="text placeholder" rel="Alle vacatures" value="" />
<input type="text" id="near" title="Locatie" name="location" class="text placeholder" rel="Locatie" value="" />
```

I use the same code on the "Bekijk CV's" page, which is actually working:
http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl/cv/

```
<input type="text" id="search" title="" name="s" class="text placeholder resume-search" rel="CV's zoeken" value="" /
```

I already spent like 2 hours to fix this and think this is the good time to ask you guys for help.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** It apears that it kinda conflicts with the jquery file. 
If i delete the following line, the searchbar works, but the slider wont anymore:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no rel attribute for input elements, and on those elements where it does exist it describes the relationship between the current document and that which it links to. Using it to store placeholder data is a horrific abuse of semantics. Don't do that.

Comment: So, what is your suggestion? I'm not helped with an analysis only. Besides that, wheater it is valid or not, it works on the other link and not on the homepage. I do get your point though

Comment: Err. Throw it out and start from scratch with a more sensible design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Quentin is right.  You should not use a `rel` attribute for an `input` element.

You could use a simple bit of jQuery to get the effect you want

```
$('#search').val('Alle vacatures');
$('#near').val('Locatie');

$('#search, #near').focusin(function(){
    $(this).val('')
});

$('#search, #near').focusout(function(){
    if ($('#search').val() == ""){
        $('#search').val('Alle vacatures');    
    }
    if ($('#near').val() == ""){
        $('#near').val('Locatie');    
    }
});
```

You set the values, which shows in the input.  When you focus in on either input, the value is removed.  Once the input loses focus, if there is nothing added to the field, the value is placed back again.

http://jsfiddle.net/2HY7y/

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: That is an alternative and not a fix. It should simply work since it also works on the other page. I will keep this in mind if everything else fails :) thank you